Files being indexed twice in SonarCloud scan
I’m learning how to integrate SonarCloud with Github Actions in a personal project. The Github repository that I am using can be accessed by clicking here.
The solution I am developing was created with version 8.0 of .NET. By default, all source code is present in the src directory. All test projects (unit, integration and functional) are present in the tests directory.
My Github Actions workflow that is integrating with SonarCloud is called Develop Workflow, and can be accessed by clicking here.
name: Develop Workflow

on:
    push:
        branches: ["develop"]

permissions:
    contents: write

jobs:
    build:
        name: Build
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            - name: Checkout code
              uses: actions/checkout@v3

            - name: Setup .NET Core
              uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
              with:
                dotnet-version: '8.0.x'

            - name: Restore dependencies
              run: dotnet restore
              working-directory: src

            - name: Build solution
              run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
              working-directory: src

    unit_test:
        name: Unit Tests
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        needs: build
        steps:
            - name: Checkout code
              uses: actions/checkout@v3

            - name: Setup .NET Core
              uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
              with:
                dotnet-version: '8.0.x'

            - name: Restore dependencies
              run: dotnet restore
              working-directory: tests/Postech.PhaseOne.GroupEight.TechChallenge.UnitTests

            - name: Build test project
              run: dotnet build --no-restore
              working-directory: tests/Postech.PhaseOne.GroupEight.TechChallenge.UnitTests

            - name: Run tests
              run: dotnet test --verbosity normal
              working-directory: tests/Postech.PhaseOne.GroupEight.TechChallenge.UnitTests

    functional_test:
        name: Functional Tests
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        needs: build
        steps:
            - name: Checkout code
              uses: actions/checkout@v3

            - name: Setup .NET Core
              uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3

            - name: Restore dependencies
              run: dotnet restore
              working-directory: tests/Postech.PhaseOne.GroupEight.TechChallenge.FunctionalTests

            - name: Build test project
              run: dotnet build --no-restore
              working-directory: tests/Postech.PhaseOne.GroupEight.TechChallenge.FunctionalTests

            - name: Run tests
              run: dotnet test --verbosity normal
              working-directory: tests/Postech.PhaseOne.GroupEight.TechChallenge.FunctionalTests

    sonarcloud:
      name: SonarCloud Scan
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      needs: build
      steps:
        - name: Checkout code
          uses: actions/checkout@v3
          with:
            fetch-depth: 0

        - name: Setup .NET
          uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
          with:
            dotnet-version: '8.0.x'
        
        - name: Install Java 17
          uses: actions/setup-java@v3
          with:
            java-version: '17'
            distribution: 'temurin'

        - name: Cache SonarCloud packages
          uses: actions/cache@v3
          with:
            path: ~\sonar\cache
            key: ${{ runner.os }}-sonar
            restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-sonar

        - name: Cache SonarCloud scanner
          id: cache-sonar-scanner
          uses: actions/cache@v3
          with:
            path: .\.sonar\scanner
            key: ${{ runner.os }}-sonar-scanner
            restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-sonar-scanner

        - name: Install SonarCloud scanner
          if: steps.cache-sonar-scanner.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
          run: |
            mkdir -p ./.sonar/scanner
            dotnet tool update dotnet-sonarscanner --tool-path ./.sonar/scanner

        - name: Install dotnet coverage
          run: dotnet tool install --global dotnet-coverage

        - name: Solution Scan
          env:
            SONAR_TOKEN: ${{secrets.SONAR_TOKEN}}
            GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PAT_TOKEN }}
          run: |
           ./.sonar/scanner/dotnet-sonarscanner begin /k:"lucasdirani_GithubActionsTest" /o:"tech-challenge-arquitetura-sistemas-net" /d:sonar.token="${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}" /d:sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=coverage.xml /d:sonar.sources="src/" /d:sonar.tests="tests/" /d:sonar.host.url="https://sonarcloud.io"
           dotnet build src/Postech.PhaseOne.GroupEight.TechChallenge.sln --no-incremental
           ~/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-coverage collect "dotnet test src/Postech.PhaseOne.GroupEight.TechChallenge.sln" -f xml -o "coverage.xml"
           ./.sonar/scanner/dotnet-sonarscanner end /d:sonar.token="${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}"

As my test and source code directories are separate, I followed the recommendations from the official SonarCloud documentation, and indicated their respective locations in the dotnet-sonarscanner begin command.
./.sonar/scanner/dotnet-sonarscanner begin /k:"lucasdirani_GithubActionsTest" /o:"tech-challenge-arquitetura-sistemas-net" /d:sonar.token="${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}" /d:sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=coverage.xml /d:sonar.sources="src/" /d:sonar.tests="tests/" /d:sonar.host.url="https://sonarcloud.io"

However, during the execution of the pipeline (the last execution I performed can be found by clicking here), for some reason the scanner is pointing out the indexing error shared right after.

ERROR: File
src/Postech.PhaseOne.GroupEight.TechChallenge.Api/Setup/RepositorySetup.cs
can’t be indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns
produce disjoint sets for main and test files

I’m confused by the error since the RepositorySetup file is only being referenced in a single project in my solution. I would like to ask for help to resolve the problem in question. I tried several alternatives, but the error persists regardless of what I do.

If you remove the caching, does the error also occur?

@Bademeister Yes, the error continues even after removing the cache. I also made an attempt by removing the sonar.sources and sonar.tests parameters from the sonarscan command. When I did this, the analysis was completed successfully, but when accessing SonarCloud (https://sonarcloud.io/summary/new_code?id=lucasdirani_GithubActionsTest&branch=develop), not a single line of code from the solution was extracted. I really have no idea how to proceed.

I have no experience with .NET, so I can't really give you any helpful tips. Ask your question in the SonarSource community. There are also SonarSource employees there.
